# How is $_GET set in this image-resize code?

Tags: php, mysql, get, image-resizing

I am working with a script for resizing images. I seem to be getting an error:

**Error: no image was specified**
Probably because of this code in the script(image.php):

```
    if (!isset($_GET['image']))
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
        echo 'Error: no image was specified';
        exit();

}
```

**Here is what I'm doing(profile.php)**:

```
$your_image = $row['Image'];
$path_to_image = $row['PortraitPath'];
$width = 100;
$height = 100;

echo "<img src=\'/image.php/{$your_image}?width={$width}&amp;height={$height}&amp;cropratio=1:1&amp;image={$path_to_img}\' alt=\'Alt text goes here.\' />";
```

Therefore, I am reading `$your_image` and `$path_to_image` from a MySQL table, and then putting it in the `img source`. As mentioned above, obviously, image is not set, that is why I am getting that first error. What I don't get is, how will the image actually even be set with my `img src` code? Aren't I simply displaying the actual image? Then how will image even be set if a picture is simply being displayed? Thank you.

Comment: Did you copy this code from somewhere?  Obviously the previous location received the image from the GET url rather than the database.

Comment: Apart from needing to remove the `\` before your `'`'s in the string I see no problem.

Comment: @ Fosco - Correct..Doh..I'm now thinking how can I even resize the picture when I've already saved it in the database....I should resize it right after the picture has been uploaded...hmm

Comment: @newbie-25 : resizing of an image consisting as a string rather then a file if just as easy, in GD with `imagecreatefromstring()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to source a php file instead an image, you need to tell your php file that the output will be an image.
You can do this using the php header() function, like this:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
```

Here is some reference:   [php header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

About the address you are point to, isn't a bit weird? You have a slash right after the .php, which suggest that you are trying to access some folder... Did you tested this url to see if a real image are being outputted on the screen?

Hope this can help you =)

Answer (score 0):

The URl for the image contains `?foo=bar&this=that&image=path`. These variables will be passed to the image.php script in the $_GET array.

Answer (score 0):

As a word of warning, in your `profile.php`'s code I saw this fragment:

`image={$path_to_img}`

Depending on how you deal with the value of `$_GET['image']` this may result in a [RFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_File_Inclusion) vulnerability. The user could forge a GET request to `image.php` with their own "image" path.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things that I noticed, I'm not sure how much of the code you modified before posting it here...

1a) Don't escape the single quotes if you are using double quotes to encompass it.

OR

1b) Change the escaped single quotes to escaped double quotes.

2) In the URL you are using `$path_to_img` but the variable you have defined is `$path_to_image`.  Make them consistent.